# How to set header for tclhttpRequest in Delphi

Tags: delphi, post, httprequest, bad-request

I want to post some data to a website which requires to send a key like this through the header part: x-tot:2323
I've tried this code:

```
clhttpRequest.Header.Authorization:= 'x-tot:2323';
```

but returns error 400 bad request.

appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: `clHttpRequest.Header.ExtraFields.Add( 'x-tot:2323' );` took me 7 seconds for a Google result of https://www.delphipraxis.net/1475024-post8.html, assuming the variable is of type `TclHttpRequest`.

Comment: Yea that's the way.. Ive found it myself tho but this search never came up for me after hours of searches! Thanks mate.